# Help with adding secondary IPs to Netplan on Ubuntu 20.04 AWS EC2 instance

Tags: netplan, amazon-ec2

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 ec2 instance. I need to add three more persistent private IP addresses in addition to the primary. I'm familiar with the old way of doing this, but I have no experience with Netplan. Here is what I have (by default) in my 50-cloud-init.yaml file:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: false
            match:
                macaddress: 02:63:b0:5e:8d:8d
            set-name: eth0
    version: 2
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can add three secondary addresses to this machine
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please see: `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static_multiaddress.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 EC2 instance:
First assign a secondary private ip to the interface: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html#assignIP-existing.
Then configure Linux via netplan: https://easyscale.net/aws-ec2-ubuntu-18-04-secondary-ip-with-netplan/ (though I used /24 instead of /20)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In this question answer site it is not sufficient to provide link only answers. URLs change all the time. Please edit your answer and add the necessary steps in the answer so that one can solve the problem without the links. Keep the links as references. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) in the site's help.